# Привязать одинаковые ячейки C# datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

[image: Таблица 1]

Задать ограничение или привязать ячейки "Да/Нет" к определенному месяцу, чтобы они не пересекались в другими месяцами.

[image: Таблица 2]

Данные должны записаться в таблицу.
На данный момент считает Январь-Февраль 3, потому что считает ещё Февраль-Март

Что смог сделать с помощью LINQ:

Посчитать количество Января-Февраля

```
            var mounth = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows
            group row by row.Cells[5].Value into res
            where res.Key != null
            select new { res.Key, Count = res.Count() };
        Dictionary<object, int> result = mounth.ToDictionary(arg => arg.Key, arg => arg.Count);
        int JanFeb;
        result.TryGetValue("Январь-Февраль", out JanFeb);
```

Количество Нет. Считает все "Нет"

```
            var atest1 = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows
                     group row by row.Cells[5].Value into res
                     where res.Key != null
                     select new { res.Key, Count = res.Count() };
        Dictionary<object, int> result1 = atest1.ToDictionary(arg => arg.Key, arg => arg.Count);

        int memberpass;
        result1.TryGetValue("Нет", out memberpass);
        MessageBox.Show(memberpass.ToString());
```

[Так же опирался на этот источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639152/check-duplicate-and-sum-values-in-datagridview-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно посчитать количество "Да" по группам?
Добавьте фильтрацию именно с этим условием:

```
from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows
where row.Cells[6].Value == "Да"
group row by row.Cells[5].Value into res
where res.Key != null
select new { res.Key, Count = res.Count() };
```

Comment: Фильтр сработал добавил `where row.Cells[6].Value.ToString()=="Да"` Спасибо за ответ